# Running python program with arguments from another program

Tags: python, list, loops, subprocess, parameter-passing

I want to call a python program from current program,

```
def multiply(a):
    return a*5
mul = sys.argv[1]
```

I saved this file as `test.py`.so from the current file I'm calling it but i want to run the code in parallel like multiprocessing queue,But its not working.
what I tried so far,

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
cwd = os.getcwd()
l =  [20,5,12,24]
for i in np.arange(len(l)):
    os.system('python test.py multiply[i]')
```

I want to run the main script for all list items parallelly like multiprocessing. How to achieve that?

Comment: Please repeat the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html), it shows you how to reuse Python code that is stored in a file.

Comment: No...I want to make it in a way...that everything can be executed at once...like using a subprocess ..can you help me in that way..

Comment: I want to run them parallely for all list items..it will explain a lot..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your program work like that using that the os.system, you need to change the test.py file a bit:

```
import sys

def multiply(a):
    return a*5

n = int(sys.argv[1])
print(multiply(n))
```

This code written like this takes the second element (the first one is just the name of the file) of argv that it took when you executed it with os.system and converted it to an integer, then executed your function (multiply by 5).

In these cases though, it's way better to just import this file as a module in your project.